# Emulator Problem ( Emulator: createOrGetGlobalVkEmulation: Warning: Vulkan 1.1 APIs missing from device )

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-emulator, vulkan

I have created an emulator with Android Studio API30, when I lunch the emulator, I got some errors ;

```
12:29   Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkBindBufferMemory2 not found

12:29   Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkBindImageMemory2 not found

12:29   Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkGetDeviceGroupPeerMemoryFeatures not found

12:29   Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkCmdSetDeviceMask not found

12:29   Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkCmdDispatchBase not found

12:29   Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkGetImageMemoryRequirements2 not found

12:29   Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements2 not found

12:29   Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkGetImageSparseMemoryRequirements2 not found

12:29   Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkTrimCommandPool not found

12:29   Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkCreateSamplerYcbcrConversion not found

12:29   Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkDestroySamplerYcbcrConversion not found

12:29   Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkCreateDescriptorUpdateTemplate not found

12:29   Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkDestroyDescriptorUpdateTemplate not found

12:29   Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkUpdateDescriptorSetWithTemplate not found

12:29   Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_1 check failed: vkGetDescriptorSetLayoutSupport not found

12:29   Emulator: createOrGetGlobalVkEmulation: Warning: Vulkan 1.1 APIs missing from device
```

CPU : Ryzen 5 , all updates are complete for flutter, android studio, sdks and also all cpu updates.

Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to disable Vulkan apps that are connected to the emulator. So you have to add the following lines to `~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini` file. You should create the file if it is not there.

```
Vulkan = off
GLDirectMem = on
```

Save the file and restart Android Emulator.